# Job Scheduler doesn't work if app is killed

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have looked at many other threads on this. However, none of this seems to help.

I need to set up job scheduler that runs everyday at 3PM.

Here is my service class:

```
public class AttendanceCheckScheduler extends JobService {
    private AttendanceCheckTask mAttendanceCheckTask;

    private static final String TAG = "AttendanceCheckScheduler";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

        mAttendanceCheckTask = new AttendanceCheckTask();
        mAttendanceCheckTask.execute();
        jobFinished(params, false);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {

        mAttendanceCheckTask.cancel(true);
        return false;
    }

    private class AttendanceCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // some long running task...
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I am scheduling the job in ActivityHome.

```
public class ActivityHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int JOB_ID = 100;
    private JobScheduler jobScheduler;
    protected JobInfo jobInfo;

    private static final String TAG = "ActivityHome";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // other irrelevant codes here...

        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, AttendanceCheckScheduler.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName);

        builder.setPeriodic(5000); // every 5 seconds for testing purpose...
        builder.setPersisted(true);

        jobInfo = builder.build();

        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

        Toast.makeText(this, "job scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Everythings seems to work fine and I am receiving the toast message `Task run` every 5 seconds as set above.

But when the app is killed (by clearing all task in multitask window), I stop receiving the toast messages.

How do I keep it running even if the app is killed ?

P.S: I want some task to perform once everyday at 3PM.

Comment: You should focus first on fixing your `JobService`. You are not calling `jobFinished()` (which you need to do), and you should not be using an `AsyncTask` (use a plain thread or something else that does not involve the main application thread). In general, a well-written `JobService` should not be affected by the overview screen. However, some device manufacturers have their own task managers that behave like Force Stop does (button on your app's page in Settings), and that will cancel jobs. There is little that you can do about those devices.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that you cannot use `JobScheduler` to do something at 3pm specifically, that your 5-second polling period will not work on all Android versions, and that using a `Toast` for diagnostics is not a good idea (use LogCat, please).

Comment: Sumit Do you know how JobScheduler works after Killing app?

Answer (score 1):

For background task for long time when your app is killed, you need to implement `AlarmManager` or `WorkManager`. `WorkManager` was in beta but now its ready only for Android X, just implement the dependency and copy paste `WorkManager` class code from google and put your task.

`WorkManager` latest dependency:

```
 implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this article. Here it says you have to call jobFinished() in your onPostExecute method of the asyncTask to let the system know the job is done.

> jobFinished() requires two parameters: the current job, so that it
>   knows which wakelock can be released, and a boolean indicating whether
>   you’d like to reschedule the job. If you pass in true, this will kick
>   off the JobScheduler’s exponential backoff logic for you

I hope it helps.

[Scheduling jobs like a pro with JobScheduler](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129)

Answer (score -1):

There is an option not to kill the application, but it is very rude and it's the hack:
In your Manifest -> inside activity tag -> Add following line

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Your app not show in recent apps history. So user can't kill the app.

Information is obtained by reference: https://code-examples.net/en/q/26c6cf8

Comment: So that needs to be added to every activity of that application?

Comment: It's not a good answer because when you are using the application and tap on the app history button you can see the app in background and  you can kill it